# Prestashop module not showing in the list

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.5.2.
This is my code:

```php
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class plugin extends Module {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'plugin';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = 1.0;
        $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
        $this->need_instance = 1;


        $this->displayName = $this->l('Module');
        $this->description = $this->l('ASDFGHJKL');
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (parent::install() == false) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall()) {
            Db::getInstance()->Execute('DELETE FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'mymodule`');
        }
        parent::uninstall();
    }
}
?>
```

File is named plugin.php and is located in /modules/plugin.

When I open module manager, the module does not appear. In any category.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which prestashop version are you using?

Comment: Updated the question @TheDrot

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. Remember that you need to actually install the plugin under modules -> module -> module catalog and click install